# postgresql 10 on FreeBSD sporadically returns incorrect float values running the exact same query

Tags: python, postgresql, freebsd, postgresql-10

We've been running postgresql server 9.6 on FreeBSD 11.2 so far and tried to upgrade to version 10.4 last month. This week we tried again to upgrade to 10.5 hoping the issue might be solved.

After the upgrade, we experience the following behavior running this select query:

```
SELECT assets_daily.close 
FROM assets_daily 
  INNER JOIN assets_daily_conditions ON (assets_daily.id = assets_daily_conditions.daily_id) 
WHERE (assets_daily.asset_id = 139 AND assets_daily_conditions.condition_id = 117 AND assets_daily.close_diff_10 IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER BY assets_daily.date DESC
```

Using either python libraries or just using the psql command client tool that comes with postgresql we will sporadically get different assets_daily.close values. So instead of the correct value, `10.8` we would get `0` or even more strange `>.8`

Running the same query again and again, this happens about every 10000 runs. Sometimes right after 50, sometimes after 20000 or even more. So it's very sporadic.

Here's some more information: assets_daily.close is a float8 field. The tables are not small (assets_daily has 8 million records, assets_daily_conditions about 45 million records). There are no other clients or processes running that are accessing the database at the same time. We updated FreeBSD to the latest 11.2R and tried both installing postgresql-server10 using the binary and the ports versions. The server logs show no errors and there's plenty of free memory.

We first tried to upgrade using pg_upgrade but after we got the errors also tried to pg_dump from 9.6 and re-import from scratch into 10.5. Same results.

I know this is hard/impossible to reproduce unless we provide a really detailed example with a dataset etc. But my hope is that maybe someone out there has similar issues and maybe even a solution or has some hints/ideas in what direction we could start looking for one.

Comment: Not sure whether this will be related, but what's the value of your `--disable-float8-byval` option?

Comment: @favoretti: the default, but I also don't think it's related as we don't use any special functions here. Our configure options: --with-libraries=/usr/local/lib' '--with-includes=/usr/local/include' '--enable-thread-safety' '--disable-debug' '--enable-nls' '--without-pam' '--with-openssl' '--without-gssapi'

Comment: What happens if you cast the value to numeric with fixed precision, does it still vary?

Comment: @favoretti yes I will get an error then that it can't cast ">.2" to float which is how I found the issue in the first place. If it gives back 0 it's more hideous as it'll pass...

Comment: Check if problem goes away in case you disable parallelism via `max_parallel_workers_per_gather=0`. There's an open bug #15324, looks related: https://postgr.es/m/153417684333.10284.11356259990921828616@wrigleys.postgresql.org

Comment: @vyegorov: Thank you so much! That actually does work as a workaround, yes. We have to figure out what the performance impact is going to be setting this to 0 but we now no longer get these sporadic non-float values. So this is a big step forward, also knowing now that there's a bug we can track and try again once it's solved.

Comment: @Marco, you can disable parallelism for individual transactions via `SET LOCAL`, no need to disable it instance-wide.
Or you can create a dedicated user for this particular query and do `ALTER USER … SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather=0`